Operator Product Expansion (OPE) coefficients of free massless theory
Consider the action of the free massless bosonic theory in $2+1D$
$$
S = \int d^3x \partial_{\mu}\phi(x) \partial^{\mu} \phi(x).
$$
The single-particle spectrum (on the surface of a sphere) is given by
$$
E_{n,m} = (n+1/2), \quad n=0,1,2,3, ...., \quad m=-n, .... , n-1, n
$$
I can obtain all the scaling dimensions (using state-operator correspondence) of the operators by constructing the Fock space from the single particle spectrum of the theory. For example, you can put two bosons in the n=0 state, and the resulting state will have energy $1$ and total angular momentum $0$. Hence it is an opertor with scaling dimension $1$ and $L=0$. And you can continue filling up single-particle levels and thereby obtain all the scaling dimensions and angular momentum of the fields. It is a very simple numerical exercise.
But how would I obtain all the OPEs of this theory?
Since this is the free theory, I would think that obtaining all the OPEs should be possible in a similar manner from the Fock space.

When three primary operators are given as polynomials in the field and derivatives, OPE coefficients can be computed using Wick's theorem. But enumerating the primaries in the first place is tedious.

@ConnorBehan Thanks for your comment. I know how to find the OPE coefficients when only scalar primaries are involved. For example, in case of $\phi_2(x)$, $\phi_4(x)$ and $\phi_6(x)$. However I don't know how to compute the OPEs when spinful primaries are involved. Also, what do you do when when you want to compute OPEs when one of the field is a descendant. Can you give me atleast one detailed calculation for spinful parimaries? And maybe also when descendants are involved.
It will be really appreciated

Hi eon97. Is this from a reference? Which page?

If you don't care whether your operators are primary or descendant, the job is easy. Wick's theorem at the end of the day will give $\left < D \phi(x_1) D^\prime \phi(x_2) \right >$ where $D$ and $D^\prime$ are differential operators that you can just bring out of the expectation value.

Hi @Qmechanic, thanks. Not from a reference (at least I don't know of any particular one). I need the OPEs of the free theory to proceed with my current project.

@ConnorBehan, thanks for the comment. While we can take out the differential operators, there are still a few issues I am struggling with. For example, what is the normalization of an operator like $\phi^2(x)D\phi(x)$? How would you compute the OPE between the following operators $\phi_1(x) = \partial_{\nu}\partial_{\mu}\phi^2(x)$,
$\phi_2(x) = \partial_{\nu}\partial_{\mu}\phi^2(x)$ and $\phi_3(x) = \phi^2(x)$? I need an example.
